# Counting element from tuples and turning result in dictionnary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 3-tuples (with some duplicates inside) and I need to turn this list into a dictionary of dictionary.

The first dictionary has the first two elements of the tuple as key, and the inside one has the last element as a key.

Example :

```
Input : [('a','b','c'), ('a','b','c'), ('a','b','d'), ('b','c','d')]

Output : {('a','b') : {'c' : 2, 'd' : 1}, ('b','c') : {'d' : 1}}
```

I have the 'human' version :

```
from collections import defaultdict
def count(list_tupl):
    topdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for tup in list_tupl :
        topdict [tup[:2]][tup[2]] += 1
    return topdict
```

But I'm looking for a more pythonic version with dict comprehension.
Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I really do not see any thing wrong with your solution. A comprehension seems contrived here, and will likely be less efficient.